# iOS switching between subviews common pattern

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface

Is there any common pattern for switching between small subviews in iOS applications? For example, I'm making some kind of image editing application and I have instruments panel view like the [panel view in interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQb60.png).

I want different views with sliders and icons to change in the upper-right area of this view when appropriate buttons in the bottom panel are pushed. What approach is better in this situation? 
Making every subview have a xib and load them every time the button is pushed?

Making subviews in Interface Builder and hiding all except one when the button is pushed? Maybe there is some handy approach to do this?
And I'm using Auto Layout; how should I handle constraints to center the content and make it fill its area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred approach is this:

1) Create a container view in your view controller

2) Create independent view controllers for each subview (this makes sense if your subviews are interactive and have some controls and logic of their own). I like to create them in my storyboard, give them a custom size to help you design them in Interface Builder, and then load them in code by using `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`.

3) Add the child view controllers, ensuring that the visible one is on top (by doing something like `[self.containerView bringSubviewToFront:childVC1.view]`.

4) As you switch between the child VCs, bring the view of the current one to front.

5). For communication between the parent and child VCs you can use delegates, to prevent a retain cycle.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. Can you answer some little questions then? Maybe it's better then to do the same with that whole instruments panel? I made it in separate xib and load it after button is pushed on main controller. And for each loaded "small" subview with controller should I make layout constraints in code then?

Comment: I don't think I had to set any constraints in code in similar situations (which is lucky, cause doing it is a pain). As long as you lay out your child VCs in IB, and also correctly set the frame of the child VC's view, you should be good.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "do the same with that whole instruments panel". Do you mean have a copy of all the buttons in each child VC?

Comment: No, what i tried to explain is that I made my panel (which is in attached screenshot) as a separate view in xib (without controller) and loaded it in main controller. I was asking if I should place this panel in separate controller, and made separate controllers for each "sub-panel". But I think the answer is yes, so I already did it, and now my storyboard looks like this https://postimg.org/image/e7t7pc4gh/ . For now It looks like convenient way:) If im doing it right..